# Select Count() with dynamic SOQL - how to stay in Governor Limits?

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, map, dynamic-soql

I am trying to fix my code so I don't hit any governor limits on my SOQL queries.

Long story short:  I am just learning on how to use maps, but I'm trying to figure out how I can do a SelectCount FROM the records IN the map.  I have 14 Select count statements that I must summarize in a VF Table.  In terms of efficiency, with 3 records I have 13 queries already.  I may have 2000 records.  This isn't all of my code, but once I get this, I got the rest.

They are generated dynamically.  How do I switch my below Code to something Better Written™?

```
Results = database.Query(Soql)

  //then add it to the map... but now what?
  map<id, object__c> mapResult = new Map<Id, object__c>(Results);



For(wrapperAccount eachWrap:Wrapper){

   String StringID = eachWrap.userObj.Id; //String ID referenced in soql

   if (x > Y){

      eachwrap.NumOfSomething=database.countQuery(soqlNumSomething);

   }elseif(Y>X){

      eachwrap.NumofSomethingElse=database.countQuery(soqlNumSomethingElse);

   }elseif for another 12 times. 

Example of count query: String SOQL = 'Select Count() FROM object__c WHERE 
ID IN :someList AND otherID__c =:stringID';
```

Each query is unique, cannot be done via rollup summaries, and can't be done on a trigger.  It has to be reloaded anytime a change is made on the page, since the user can make changes and I have to reflect that.

Help Please! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add a group by say ID, then put the totals into a map and pass the value into the wrapper. One query for all

for example:

```
Map<ID,Decimal> userToCount = New Map<ID,Decimal>();

AggregateResult[] results = [Select Count(something) cnt, 
       OwnerID From Opportunity Group By OwnerID]; //add in the appropriate WHERE clause

for(AggregateResult ar : results)
    userToCount.put((ID)ar.get('id'),(Integer)ar.get('cnt'));
```

then when constructing wrapper pass in the value from the `userToCount.get(THEID)`
making sure you account for the possibility of null values (no records found int he aggregate query

Comment: Thanks for the response!! I'm going to try this now.  Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey man, sorry to bug you.  I'm loopy with lack of sleep.  How would I exactly get 12 different SELECT statements - do I 1) Have 12 "Aggregate Result statements", or 2) have 1 Aggregate result statement, just 12 statements in comma delimited format which are all Select Counts.?

Comment: Not sure what you mean....You populated the userToCount map with ALL results (calculate from the one aggregateresult you would need to build your wrapper, then when building the wrapper you pass in the appropriate Decimal result instead of doing a query in the wrapper. You need to structure your wrapper in a way that it provides what is needed to the methods using it. Hard to says how to exactly do it as each case if different and your OP is lacking the remaining detail